# Which Rendering Engine does Angular 6 use - Renderer2 or Ivy Renderer?

Tags: angular

I'm getting confused about rendering engine that Angular 6 and Angular 7 are using. Since, Ivy renderer is not in completed state to date (March'19). But Angular team says that they have exposed some Ivy renderer APIs in Angular 6.

Please someone help me out to clarify about the rendering engines used by Angular 6 and Angular 7.

Comment: I am not an expert in ivy renderer, but I think only some of the features are available on the Beta versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default angular 6 and 7 still use the old renderer (Renderer2)
But the beta version of Ivy can be enabled

- https://medium.com/lacolaco-blog/quick-start-for-enabling-angular-v6-ivy-compiler-161ef492e243
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21706

On Angular 8 you can opt-in in Ivy Preview

- https://medium.com/lacolaco-blog/quick-start-for-enabling-angular-v6-ivy-compiler-161ef492e243
- https://blog.angular.io/a-plan-for-version-8-0-and-ivy-b3318dfc19f7

but to quote the last link regarding angular 8

> Ivy will not be ready for all use cases. Some features such as i18n or Angular Universal will likely not have full compatibility yet in the preview. Our language service will not be functional during the Ivy preview.

Answer (score 4):

From Angular v4 <= v7 it uses the `ViewEngine`.
And also the `Renderer2` method for rendering.

In angular 8 `ivy` will be optional and in angular 9 it will be default.